# How do I program the selection of a layer and change that layers attributes

Tags: graphics32

How do I program the selection of a layer and change that layers attributes,i.e. visibility, size, colour?

I have programmed the creation of about 1000 layers but I want to individually change each layer at different times.

Comment: paste code if it is possible..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then amend your question so that others may help you.